# PowerShell partial zip file name

Tags: powershell, zip, unzip

Currently I have a code that extracts a zip file that is uploaded nightly and it has the name `CallRecording_1-000-XXXXXXXX` the X's represent the date and time that the zip file was generated. What I would like to do is have a powershell script that looks for the partial name. So for example it would look for just `CallRecording_1-000` or `CallRecording`.

At the moment I have the following script:

```
#expand archive into folder
expand-archive ("Y:\CallRecording_1-000.zip") -destinationPath $folder

#rename zip file with yesterdays date
$yesDateName = $yesDate + ".zip"
Rename-Item "Y:\CallRecording_1-000.zip" -NewName $yesDateName
```

The scripts that I have found previously that use partial names seems to focus mostly on the extension rather than the name itself.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you only expect 1 zip file however I tailored this answer around the possibility of having more than 1

- We are going to use `Get-ChildItem` to get any zip files from y:\ that match 'CallRecordings*.zip'
- We then pipe these files one at a time to the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet where we

  - assign the extraction folder
  - unzip the file
  - and then rename the file.

`$i` is used to allow us different names for our renamed zip file in case there are more than 1 being processed.

```
    $i = 0
    Get-ChildItem -Path 'Y:\' -Filter 'CallRecording*.zip' | ForEach-Object -Process {
        $extractFolder = "C:\temp\$($_.BaseName)"
        $_ | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath $extractFolder 
        
        # ($? tells us if the last command completed successfully)
        if ($?) {
            # only rename file if Expand-Archive was successful
            $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd') + "_$((++$i)).zip")
        }
    }
```